# openCV support for vista 64x

Tags: windows-vista, opencv, 64-bit

I am trying to install **OpenCV** over **windows vista 64x** but it's shows a fatal error.
I tried everything I can but it is useless.

Does openCV work on vista 64?

How do I get rid of this problem?

Please help .

thanx in advance

Comment: Now it does support 64bit and 32bit, you have different libraries in the package. I just mention it just in case anybody finds this old question and thinks it is still valid.

Comment: yes you are right Jav. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, OpenCV does NOT support 64bit OS yet.

Comment: is there any recommended video manipulation library that can work over windows 64x?